# How to run 3 tier app on docker, running on 3 different centos using vagrant,

Tags: php, mysql, docker, vagrant

I am working on Vagrant, and trying to create 3 tier Web App, i install 3 Centos on Vagrant using same vagrant file.

Each Centos has docker, 1 centos has database, 2 centos has php apache server, 3 centos has php apache and client side code to display result.

All three are sync and work fine, but when i created docker container for first MYSQL database, i was able to connect it locally on same Vm but cannot connect through 2nd VM with apache and PHP.

**Can anyone help me?**

Also i have to test this 3 tier web app on Docker compose.

How can i do it?
Do i have to run all 3 on different VM ?

Answer (score 1):

In this configuration as you've described it, most of the configuration is identical to something you'd set up without Docker.  (And there's nothing wrong with that!)  Make sure to:

- For each containerized service, run it with a `-p` option to publish some port out of Docker space; for example, the MySQL service you'd run with `docker run -p 3306:3306 ... mysql:5.7`.
- To connect between services, connect to the IP address of the VM hosting the service and the published port number (the first number after the `-p` option).  (A service-discovery system like [Consul](https://consul.io/) can help remember which service is on which VM.)

You can't use Docker Compose with this setup, beyond it possibly being a more convenient way to record each individual service's startup options.

If using Docker Compose or the other Docker-native tooling is important to you, you'd have to run this on at most one VM.  (If you have a Linux host, you don't need a VM at all; MacOS and some Windows setups have desktop applications that can hide the VM fairly well.)  Since a Docker container has some similarities to a VM (like an isolated filesystem) more developer-oriented setups tend to avoid VMs entirely and don't seem to frequently involve Vagrant.  What you're describing here is a perfectly good deployment architecture, but it's something you'd set up with a Packer/Ansible stack with Docker as an implementation detail, rather than something that's Docker first.

Comment: this is assignment for me, so i have to it this way.

Comment: also i used this command
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name dmysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=vagrant my-mysql

here my-mysql is my image of mysql-server, which build with database, and script for tables, i can access those table in container on same centos, but cannot connect to it remotely from 2nd centos

Comment: still i cannot connect to database,
i tried both ip address, 192.168.10.87 this is centos ip
i cannot connect to mariadb using this,
but 172.17.0.2 this is docker ip address for mysql server,
both these ip address dont connect me to mysql docter container

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP addresses are frequently useless and you should probably never look them up.  In your example, one VM can't reach the Docker-internal IP addresses on another VM (and is probably even using the same IP addresses for its own containers).

Comment: ok, David Maze, i cannot even ping that docker ip address, so i know its not working.

Comment: ok, thanks its done, i used my centos IP to connect, my error was that i forgot to expose port in Dockerfile,